# why I am getting errors concerning non integers in bash?

Tags: bash

I have a DataCollage.txt file that contains some numbres:
1.5 9
3 10

I want to introduce some if and elif conditions concerning the data I have and I wrote a sipmle code but it turns out that it is not working with decimal numbers:

```
#!/bin/bash

Pe=( $(awk '{print $1}' ./DataCollage.txt) )
Coord=( $(awk '{print $2}' ./DataCollage.txt) )

if [[ ( $(echo "${Pe[0]} -eq 0" |bc -l ) ) || ( $(echo "${Pe[1]} -eq 0" |bc -l ) ) ] && [ ( $(echo "${Pe[0]} -ne ${Pe[1]}" |bc -l ) ) ]]; then 
echo 3 >> Resultats.txt

else
    echo 4

fi
```

once executing this file it gives me this error:

```
bash: NewDumplire_v1.sh: line 7: syntax error in conditional expression

bash: NewDumplire_v1.sh: line 7: syntax error near `]'

bash: NewDumplire_v1.sh: line 7: `if [[ ( $(echo "${Pe[0]} -eq 0" |bc -l ) ) || ( $(echo "${Pe[1]} -eq 0" |bc -l ) ) ] && [ ( $(echo "${Pe[0]} -ne ${Pe[1]}" |bc -l ) ) ]]; then'
```

could some one please give me a solution?

Just in case I tried without bc for the integer numbers using this line:

```
elif [[ ( ${Pe[0]} -eq 0 ) || ( ${Pe[1]} -eq 0 ) ]] && [ ${Pe[0]} -ne ${Pe[1]} ]; then echo 4
```

and it works.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Seems like you are mixing up single/double brackets.

Comment: Note that in `bash` that `[[` and `]]` without a space are single tokens. So `]` does not close off the second bracket in `[[`.

Comment: Please paste your script there first: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Given that all the data comes from the same file, you should probably implement the comparisons in `awk` as well. The entire `bash` script can be replaced with a single `awk` script.